# Gradle Android project compile error from Intellj Idea

Tags: android, intellij-idea, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

I had strange error time to time when I compile Android gradle project from the Idea. Sometimes problem was resolved by removing `build` folder, sometimes restart could help. It wasn't bother me that much as it happens few times a month.

Recently something completely changed after I add one more module, I constantly getting same error. Here is a log from Idea's `build.log`:

```
2016-06-17 16:46:26,659 [   1540]   INFO - der.AndroidGradleTargetBuilder - Gradle build using tasks: [:AndroidBase:App:assembleDebug, :AppCommon:assemble, :AndroidBase:assembleDebug]
2016-06-17 16:46:26,665 [   1546]   INFO - dle.util.AndroidGradleSettings - Found Android SDK home at '/opt/android' (from local.properties file)
2016-06-17 16:46:26,665 [   1546]   INFO - der.AndroidGradleTargetBuilder - About to build project 'App' located at /home/rux/code/App
2016-06-17 16:46:26,704 [   1585]   INFO - der.AndroidGradleTargetBuilder - Build JVM args: []
2016-06-17 16:46:26,705 [   1586]   INFO - der.AndroidGradleTargetBuilder - Build command line args: [-Pandroid.injected.invoked.from.ide=true, --configure-on-demand]
2016-06-17 16:46:28,876 [   3757]   INFO - .incremental.IncProjectBuilder - Android Gradle Build Target: org.gradle.tooling.GradleConnectionException: Could not execute build using Gradle installation '/home/.ruxuncrypted/.gradle/wrapper/dists/gradle-2.10-all/a4w5fzrkeut1ox71xslb49gst/gradle-2.10'.
org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.ProjectBuildException: Android Gradle Build Target: org.gradle.tooling.GradleConnectionException: Could not execute build using Gradle installation '/home/.ruxuncrypted/.gradle/wrapper/dists/gradle-2.10-all/a4w5fzrkeut1ox71xslb49gst/gradle-2.10'.
    at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.IncProjectBuilder.buildTargetsChunk(IncProjectBuilder.java:1013)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.IncProjectBuilder.buildChunkIfAffected(IncProjectBuilder.java:871)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.IncProjectBuilder.buildChunks(IncProjectBuilder.java:696)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.IncProjectBuilder.runBuild(IncProjectBuilder.java:387)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.IncProjectBuilder.build(IncProjectBuilder.java:194)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.cmdline.BuildRunner.runBuild(BuildRunner.java:137)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.cmdline.BuildSession.runBuild(BuildSession.java:294)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.cmdline.BuildSession.run(BuildSession.java:125)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.cmdline.BuildMain$MyMessageHandler$1.run(BuildMain.java:232)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.service.impl.SharedThreadPoolImpl$1.run(SharedThreadPoolImpl.java:44)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: org.gradle.tooling.GradleConnectionException: Could not execute build using Gradle installation '/home/.ruxuncrypted/.gradle/wrapper/dists/gradle-2.10-all/a4w5fzrkeut1ox71xslb49gst/gradle-2.10'.
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.ResultHandlerAdapter.onFailure(ResultHandlerAdapter.java:63)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.async.DefaultAsyncConsumerActionExecutor$1$1.run(DefaultAsyncConsumerActionExecutor.java:57)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:54)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.StoppableExecutorImpl$1.run(StoppableExecutorImpl.java:40)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.BlockingResultHandler.getResult(BlockingResultHandler.java:46)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.DefaultBuildLauncher.run(DefaultBuildLauncher.java:72)
    at com.android.tools.idea.jps.builder.AndroidGradleTargetBuilder.doBuild(AndroidGradleTargetBuilder.java:246)
    at com.android.tools.idea.jps.builder.AndroidGradleTargetBuilder.build(AndroidGradleTargetBuilder.java:129)
    at com.android.tools.idea.jps.builder.AndroidGradleTargetBuilder.build(AndroidGradleTargetBuilder.java:74)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.IncProjectBuilder.buildTarget(IncProjectBuilder.java:942)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.IncProjectBuilder.runBuildersForChunk(IncProjectBuilder.java:923)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.incremental.IncProjectBuilder.buildTargetsChunk(IncProjectBuilder.java:984)
    ... 14 more
Caused by: org.gradle.internal.event.ListenerNotificationException: Failed to notify build listener.
    at org.gradle.internal.event.AbstractBroadcastDispatch.dispatch(AbstractBroadcastDispatch.java:55)
    at org.gradle.internal.event.DefaultListenerManager$EventBroadcast$ListenerDispatch.dispatch(DefaultListenerManager.java:221)
    at org.gradle.internal.event.DefaultListenerManager$EventBroadcast$ListenerDispatch.dispatch(DefaultListenerManager.java:209)
    at org.gradle.internal.event.AbstractBroadcastDispatch.dispatch(AbstractBroadcastDispatch.java:44)
    at org.gradle.internal.event.BroadcastDispatch.dispatch(BroadcastDispatch.java:79)
    at org.gradle.internal.event.BroadcastDispatch.dispatch(BroadcastDispatch.java:30)
    at org.gradle.messaging.dispatch.ProxyDispatchAdapter$DispatchingInvocationHandler.invoke(ProxyDispatchAdapter.java:93)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy10.buildFinished(Unknown Source)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher$1.create(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:104)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher$1.create(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:93)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:90)
    at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:62)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuild(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:93)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.run(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:82)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter$DefaultBuildController.run(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:94)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.runner.BuildModelActionRunner.run(BuildModelActionRunner.java:46)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.ChainingBuildActionRunner.run(ChainingBuildActionRunner.java:35)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.runner.SubscribableBuildActionRunner.run(SubscribableBuildActionRunner.java:58)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.ChainingBuildActionRunner.run(ChainingBuildActionRunner.java:35)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:43)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:28)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.execute(ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.java:78)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.execute(ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.java:48)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ExecuteBuild.doBuild(ExecuteBuild.java:52)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:36)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.WatchForDisconnection.execute(WatchForDisconnection.java:37)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ResetDeprecationLogger.execute(ResetDeprecationLogger.java:26)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.RequestStopIfSingleUsedDaemon.execute(RequestStopIfSingleUsedDaemon.java:34)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput$2.call(ForwardClientInput.java:74)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput$2.call(ForwardClientInput.java:72)
    at org.gradle.util.Swapper.swap(Swapper.java:38)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput.execute(ForwardClientInput.java:72)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.health.DaemonHealthTracker.execute(DaemonHealthTracker.java:47)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.LogToClient.doBuild(LogToClient.java:66)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:36)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.EstablishBuildEnvironment.doBuild(EstablishBuildEnvironment.java:72)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:36)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.health.HintGCAfterBuild.execute(HintGCAfterBuild.java:41)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy$1.run(StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy.java:50)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.DaemonStateCoordinator$1.run(DaemonStateCoordinator.java:246)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:54)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.StoppableExecutorImpl$1.run(StoppableExecutorImpl.java:40)
    ... 3 more
Caused by: java.lang.LinkageError: loader constraint violation: when resolving method "com.android.builder.internal.compiler.PreDexCache.clear(Ljava/io/File;Lcom/android/utils/ILogger;)V" the class loader (instance of org/gradle/internal/classloader/MutableURLClassLoader) of the current class, com/android/build/gradle/BasePlugin$4$1, and the class loader (instance of org/gradle/internal/classloader/MutableURLClassLoader) for the method's defining class, com/android/builder/internal/compiler/PreProcessCache, have different Class objects for the type com/android/utils/ILogger used in the signature
    at com.android.build.gradle.BasePlugin$4$1.call(BasePlugin.java:394)
    at com.android.build.gradle.BasePlugin$4$1.call(BasePlugin.java:391)
    at com.android.builder.profile.ThreadRecorder$1.record(ThreadRecorder.java:55)
    at com.android.builder.profile.ThreadRecorder$1.record(ThreadRecorder.java:47)
    at com.android.build.gradle.BasePlugin$4.buildFinished(BasePlugin.java:390)
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor100.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.gradle.messaging.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:35)
    at org.gradle.messaging.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:24)
    at org.gradle.internal.event.DefaultListenerManager$ListenerDetails.dispatch(DefaultListenerManager.java:249)
    at org.gradle.internal.event.DefaultListenerManager$ListenerDetails.dispatch(DefaultListenerManager.java:229)
    at org.gradle.internal.event.AbstractBroadcastDispatch.dispatch(AbstractBroadcastDispatch.java:44)
    ... 53 more
```

I want to highlight that build from the command like works fine(`assembleDebug`, `assembleRelease` and other targets) from both gradle wrapper and standalone gradle installation.

Environment:

- Gradle version **2.10**
- compileSdkVersion **23**
- buildToolsVersion **23.0.2**
- android gradle plugin: **2.1.0**

Comment: Latest Gradle is 2.14, so you could try to update that. Otherwise, I have seen solutions that say delete the `.gradle` folder in your home directory and invalidate cache & restart IntelliJ

Comment: @cricket_007 yes, I tried to remove `build`, `.gradle` folders, cleaned Intellj cache - no luck this time. Upgrade to 2.14 didn't help as well..

Comment: Hmm, that `LinkageError` at the bottom of the question seems to indicate that a library is conflicting somewhere within the Android build tools

Comment: @cricket_007 Thank goodness! I just rebooted computer and Idea finally built app. I did literally nothing, before reboot it didn't work. Odd stuff..

Comment: I'll leave this question open for some time might be someone can find better solution than clean cache, remove `build`, `.gradle`, reimport project and reboot :) @cricket_007 thanks a lot! I'm not quite sure what kind of conflict it might be if build process works fine without Idea.

Comment: Probably something special about IntelliJ. Not sure. Glad you fixed it, though